# Override background-color by a certain percentage

Tags: php, html, css, background, percentage

I'm adding row throught a `<table>` with a `foreach`.

At some point I want a cell to have a grey background based on the percentage calcultated in PHP.

Ex: 50% means half the background of the cell with be grey the rest will stay blank | 33,33% = 1/3 of the background etc..

The problems I've met is either the text in the `<td>` got streched by any other div, if I apply the color to the `<td>` I'll also override the text later on etc..

Here is the code :

```
$percent = 1/3; // For example
$percent_friendly = number_format( $percent * 100, 2 ); //This will return 33.33

echo '<td>'.$percent_friendly.' %
    <div style="background-color: grey"> // So I want the grey to fill 33.33% of the space
    </div>
    <div style="background-color: white">
    </div>
</td>';
```

and the style applied so far :

```
table {
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
    font-size:18px;
}

table, th, td {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position:relative;
}
```

I must be missing something but CSS really isn't my thing, any explanation or help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you want to simulate a progress bar.

Comment: @VicenteOlivertRiera Yes but a fixed progress bar as the data aren't meant to move

Comment: What about creating other two div inside that one, the first one with grey background, and give them a width based on that percentage?

Comment: That was my last idea based on what you can see in the echo, but they keep streching the text who's in the <td> above

Comment: Another idea is to set a grey pixel image as a background of the td, and use the css background-size property to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple solution using 2 divs with a fixed width. The percentage is inserted directly in the markup. With setting the `<p>` to an absolute position, you shouldn't have problems with stretching the td.

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid;
}
td {
  height: 50px;
}
.progress {
    padding:0;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #555; 
    background: #ddd;
    position: relative;
}
.bar {
    height: 100%;
    background: #57a; 
}
.bar p {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    line-height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="progress">
            <div class="bar" style="width: 33.33%"><p>33.33% complete</p></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="progress">
            <div class="bar" style="width: 16.66%"><p>16.66% complete</p></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="progress">
            <div class="bar" style="width: 66.66%"><p>66.66% complete</p></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Should work in all browsers, because it only uses elements width.

Comment: It's almost what I'm looking for but I need the completion to fill the height of the cell as you can see  http://puu.sh/qqVGf/df75700a0b.png

Comment: So you want the progressbar to have the same height as the cell?

Comment: Just move the progress class to the `td` and remove the now useless `div`

Comment: @Andreas That's what I'm trying to achieve, yes.

Comment: Ok I updated it again and made it relative to the td height

Answer (score 2):

In the PHP:

```
echo "
<td>
    <div class='progress-bar' style='width: $percent_friendly%'></div>
    <span>$percent_friendly%</span>
</td>";
```

In the CSS:

```
td               { position: relative; }
td .progress-bar { position: absolute; background: grey; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; }
td span          { position: relative; }
```

This lets you apply any structural/font styles to the `td` element, and the progress bar will adjust correctly on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a linear gradient for the background color, if you don't mind it looking a bit confusing:

```
echo '<td style="background: linear-gradient(to right, grey 0%,grey '.$percent.'%,white '.$percent.'%,white 100%);">'.
            $percent_friendly.'%'.
     '</td>';
```

Be aware though that this wont work in IE9 and below